# How do I pass C objects between go packages?

Tags: go

When I try to pass a C.int from package `main` to a function in a helper package called `common`, I get the following error:

```
main.go:24: cannot use argc (type C.int) as type common.C.int in argument to common.GoStrings
```

From `common.go`:

```golang
/* 
    ...
*/
import "C"

...

func GoStrings(argc C.int, argv **C.char) (args []string) {
    // do stuff
}
```

From `main.go`:

```golang
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lpam -fPIC
#define PAM_SM_AUTH

#include <security/pam_appl.h>
*/
import "C"

...

func pam_sm_authenticate(pamh *C.pam_handle_t, flags, argc C.int, argv **C.char) C.int {
    args := common.GoStrings(argc, argv)
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to pass these objects back and forth? I've tried type casting to e.g. `common.C.int`, but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax. I'd like to be able to call `GoStrings` from multiple different main programs, and it seems like that should be allowable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't pass C types between packages. You'll need to perform any necessary type conversions within the package that is importing the C types. As per the [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

> Cgo translates C types into equivalent unexported Go types. Because
>   the translations are unexported, a Go package should not expose C
>   types in its exported API: a C type used in one Go package is
>   different from the same C type used in another.

If you have common C translation methods that you use, consider using `go generate` with a helper script to create these in each package where it is required from a master source file. Not as nice as solution as having a common library but much better than manually updating files in multiple packages.

Comment: For this situation I generally pass an `unsafe.Pointer`. This works, but you had better make sure to do sanity and error checking!